# where do i handle database violations in a spring MVC web application

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-mvc

where exactly do i handle the database exceptions in a method of a controller class . I am using hibernate to manage the database
I am having a situation wherein i have an entry of xyz@gmail.com in the database.Now when i sign up with the same email address which is primary key in my database , it shows me the default 500 error page of DataIntegrityViolation.

//i am doing this but it does not help

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView signUp(@Valid @ModelAttribute("TemporaryUser") TemporaryUser user,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("error", "An error occured, try again!");
        return model;

    }


    String checkEmail = user.getEmail();
    TemporaryUser temporaryUser;
    temporaryUser = temporaryUserService.findByEmail(checkEmail);



    if (temporaryUser != null) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("message",
                "We already have an entry with this email address , try with other email address");
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: You are handling at correct place..just find out that why it is not working.

Comment: it worked .I also think this is the correct way @Alien